# Enable pagination based on the total number of answers not the number of undeleted answers

Tags: bug, status-review, answers, deleted-answers, pagination

Generally, questions that have a large number of answers have their answers paged so that only 30 are ever displayed to the user at one time. Take, for example, [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851) which has 31 (undeleted answers) on 2 pages of answers:

[image: Page 2 of answers for the linked question]

However, users [who can see deleted posts](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) will actually see that there are 69 answers on that question, and by extension be able to see 3 pages of results

[image: Page 3 of answers for the linked question shown to users who can see deleted posts]

From this example, we see that Stack Overflow does, normally, support paging for deleted answers *and* also supports showing different paging options to users who can see deleted posts and to those who cannot.

---

It appears, however, that pagination only occurs if there are more than 30 *undeleted* answers (AnswerCount > 30). Unfortunately, this means that as long as the number of undeleted answers is below 30 all answers are displayed on one page **regardless of how many total answers there are**.

This results in some pages taking a *very* long time to load like [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584) which has 172 answers all on one page or [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/15497888) with 144 Answers.

Notice that there is no pagination displayed despite the number of answers:
[image: 172 Answers but no pagination shown]

Loading all of these answers means that the total page load time is taking somewhere between ~7.5-11.5 seconds for me to fully load a page [with 172 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584). This as compared to questions with paged results (like [the initially referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851)) which takes closer to ~0.5-1.25 seconds to fully load the 30 answers (page 1).

According to this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1649439) there are more than 1000 undeleted questions for which this applies.

---

Can pagination be based on the number of total answers and use the already existing logic to display the appropriate number of pages for users with different privilege levels?

Comment: The sorting of answers was *changed* a few months ago: Now all *deleted* answers are at the end, even in the *oldest first* view (like the non-deleted status is the primary key in the sort). Perhaps it was broken then?

Comment: (But it hasn't been registered in [the change list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), as far as I can see.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen with the same case (34 answers, 15 non-deleted answers, 1 page), all sorting are showing deleted answers under non-deleted answers. Is the sorting on SO different (and broken)? Perhaps since Trending sort?